Continuity of Solutions to Linear Programs
Suppose I have a linear program of the form $\max c^Tx$ such that $Ax \leq b$. I am curious as to the continuity of the solutions to such a linear program under perturbations of the entries of $A$.
Are there any results of the form "If $\delta > 0$ is small enough, then the solution $x^*$ to $\max c^Tx$ such that $Ax \leq b$ will be within $\epsilon$ of the solution $x^*_{\delta}$ to $\max c^Tx$ such that $(A+B\delta)x \leq b$? In this case any nonzero $B$ matrix would be sufficient for what I am looking for.
If not, are there any counterexamples where no matter how small $\delta$ is, the solution $x^*_{\delta}$ stays at least a fixed distance from $x^*$?

What do mean here by "the solution"? The set of all maximizers may be empty, and it may be infinite.

When the optimal solution is non-unique, you typically have discontinuity under perturbation.  For a simple example, consider
maximize $x_1 + x_2$ subject to $x_1 + a x_2 \le 1$, $x_1, x_2 \ge 0$.
For $0 < a < 1$, the optimal solution is $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 1/a$.  For $a > 1$, the optimal solution is $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$.  For $a = 1$, the optimal solutions are $x_1 = t$, $x_2 = 1-t$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.

But assuming the solution is nondegenerate we can avoid this case though right?

@AnotherPerson Yes.  If the solution is nondegenerate,  then for $\delta$ sufficiently small the optimal basis will be unchanged.  For such $\delta$, the optimal solution is a continuous function of $\delta$.
